# Restore Déjá Dup back up (on windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup, recover

I have a back up of user folders from an Ubuntu 15.04 System.

The back up was done via the system settings control, which as i understand uses Déjà Dup as the standard back up program.

The back up is now on a flash drive, it's files look like this:

```
duplicity-full.vol01.difftar.gz
...
duplicity-full.vol87.difftar.gz
```

as well as:

```
duplicity-full.manifest
duplicity-full.sigtar.gz
duplicity-full-signatures.sigtar.gz
duplicity-inc.33Z.to.914Z.manifest
duplicity-inc.33Z.to.914Z.vol1.difftar.gz
duplicity-new-signatures.33Z.to.914Z.sigtar.gz
```

If possible I'd like to restore these back up files on windows, or on a live Ubuntu system and then copy them onto windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from personal experience)

Requirement: the partition/drive (c) containing the backup, 2 extra drives (a + b)

1) Create a Drive (a) that boots Ubuntu, e.g. a live-usb drive.
(see: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

2) Boot the Ubuntu system, next format the second extra drive (b) to hold an ext3 file system.

3) Use the duplicity command that ships with Ubuntu to restore the backup (from c) to the ext3 drive (b)
(duplicity restore file://path-to-folder path-to-folder-to-restore-on-on-b
http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html)

Remarks:

-The files shown above in the questions indicate more than one clean back up, but a history as well, i deleted those files by hand bevor running the duplicity command.

-I saved the back up files on an ntfs system, but was not able to restore onto a ntfs system, this is the reason for the ext3 drive. This most likely was problem to a specific file and may not be mandatory.